# How to render html partially inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div and I want to set some text inside this div. Problem is my text contains HTML elements and I don't want all these elements to be rendered. I mean some elements must rendered as HTML.

Is there any way to create a div content like this?

I want to create a div element like below;

```
<div id="bodyContent">         
</div>
```

Setting with html method is not working.

```
var myHTMLContentPart1 = "<HTML><BODY>";
var myHTMLContentPart2 = "<span>hello</span>";
var myHTMLContentPart3 = "</BODY></HTML>";

$("#bodyContent").html(?);
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: I think he wants to output the parts in "quotes" as plain text, but output the span as HTML.

Comment: Does he? What does *Problem is my text contains HTML elements and I don't want all these elements to be rendered. I mean some elements must rendered as HTML.* mean?

Comment: I agree it's vague and needs some clarification, my understanding was that he means he has a mix of some tags that he wants to render as HTML and some he wants to render as text (i.e. "I don't want ALL these elements to be rendered [as HTML]" I interpret to mean he only wants SOME to be rendered as HTML and some to just appear as text). However, that's just my understanding, which could be completely wrong!

Comment: @delinear yes exactly. I want span element to be rendered as HTML but not HTML and BODY elements.

Comment: That edit has not clarified this at all

Comment: @hellzone can you tell us how you get the HTML? maybe you will get best answer instead just doing this with regex or hack with jquery

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `regex` to remove `html` or `body` tags, also you can add any tag that you want to remove like this `<\/?tagname>`

```js
html = '<html><body><span>Some Text</span></body></html>';
clean = html.replace(/<\/?html>|<\/?body>/g, '');
console.log(clean);

// For your code

var myHTMLContentPart1 = "<HTML><BODY>";
var myHTMLContentPart2 = "<span>hello</span>";
var myHTMLContentPart3 = "</BODY></HTML>";

var html = myHTMLContentPart1 + myHTMLContentPart2 + myHTMLContentPart3;

clean = html.replace(/<\/?html>|<\/?body>/g, '');

$("#bodyContent").html(clean);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bodyContent">  
</div>
```

Comment: html and body elements are just example. It can be any html element.

Comment: @hellzone You said in comments, you want span, and remove `html` and `body`!, now what? explain what do you want exactly